Not getting routes for train mode in the transitOptions using the google directions API
const directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
  try {
    const results = await directionsService.route({
      origin: 'Trichy',
      destination: 'Bangalore',
      travelMode: travelMode, // Use the selected transit mode
      transitOptions: {
        modes: ['TRAIN'],
      },
      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    });
    
    setDirectionsResponse(results);
    setDistance(results.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
    setDuration(results.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors from the Directions API
    console.error('Error fetching directions:', error);
  }

The routes I am getting only for the bus and I am not getting any routes for train even though I preferred it in the modes under transitOptions.
Also I searched the train routes between the same origin and destination in the google maps there is a routes available between two places. So one cannot say maybe there is no routes between them.
Is there any restrictions for accessing the directions api free version like for free version you should only get bus mode in the transitOptions?
or Am I making any mistakes in getting the response through directions api?
